# Print tree from a XML file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui

I have XML file like below (nested set model):

```
<abc>
  <!-- Table nested_category -->
    <nested_category>
        <category_id>31</category_id>
        <name>TEST PREP</name>
        <alias>test-prep</alias>
        <lft>5</lft>
        <rgt>8</rgt>
    </nested_category>
    <nested_category>
        <category_id>32</category_id>
        <name>cricket</name>
        <alias>cricket</alias>
        <lft>6</lft>
        <rgt>7</rgt>
    </nested_category>
    <nested_category>
        <category_id>35</category_id>
        <name>FOREST</name>
        <alias>forest2</alias>
        <lft>1</lft>
        <rgt>4</rgt>
    </nested_category>
    <nested_category>
        <category_id>36</category_id>
        <name>animal</name>
        <alias>animal</alias>
        <lft>2</lft>
        <rgt>3</rgt>
    </nested_category>
</abc>
```

I want to form a tree with ul li by parsing with jquery only.Please share some ideas to do this.As we know in nested set model, left value of a child node is always in between left and right value of parent node.I know how to parse xml with jquery but dont have any idea to looping the catgories based on lef and right value to form a tree.Thanks in Advance.

Output would be like :

```
TEST PREP
-cricket
Forest
-animal
--subtree
---subsubtree and so on.
```

Comment: I don't think you're nested set left and right values are correct. What you have now would have two trees that are not overlapping. Shouldn't the values be : `Test Prep (1:8),Forest (2:7),animal (3:6),cricket (4:5)` ?

Comment: @Anthony left and right values of my tree are absolutely correct.

Comment: Mine or yours? You should update the question showing what the final output would look like

Comment: @Anthony udated my question.

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be as below:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "xmlfilelocaltion" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        success: function(xml) {

        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );   <------------------this line

        $(xmlDoc).find('nested_category).each(function(){
           //// process children node in this.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the xml stored in a variable named xml and a div with id="someDiv"

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);

var result = "<ul>";
$(xmlDoc).find("nested_category").each(function()
          {
            result += "<li>"+ "category_id : " + $(this).find("category_id").text() +"</br>";
            result +=  "name : " + $(this).find("name").text() +"</br>";
            result +=  "alias : " + $(this).find("alias").text() +"</br>";
            result +=  "lft : " + $(this).find("lft").text() +"</br>";
            result +=  "rgt : " + $(this).find("rgt").text();
            result += "</li>";
          });
result += "</ul>";

$("#someDiv").append(result);
```

Will generate

- category_id : 31
  name : TEST PREP
  alias : test-prep
  lft : 5
  rgt : 8
- category_id : 32
  name : cricket
  alias : cricket
  lft : 6
  rgt : 7
- category_id : 35
  name : FOREST
  alias : forest2
  lft : 1
  rgt : 4
- category_id : 36
  name : animal
  alias : animal
  lft : 2
  rgt : 3

You can check out more of  $.parseXML() in 
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Hope it helps, 
Dan